# Envoy setup for grpc-web

Tags: envoyproxy, grpc-web

I'm a bit confused as to how to set up Envoy with gRPC web.

According to the [documentation](https://grpc.io/docs/platforms/web/basics/#configure-the-envoy-proxy), "we will use the Envoy proxy to forward the gRPC browser request to the backend server. You can see the complete config file in envoy.yaml".

I have a JS FE in the browser that is talking to a go backend. I'm confused about what the expectation is to deploy Envoy for the browser. Does this mean that envoy and this yaml file are running on the backend with a [frontend envoy proxy and sidecar](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/setting-up-an-envoy-front-proxy-on-amazon-ecs/) (doesn't quite match grpc documentation), or something else?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Envoy is deployed to translate gRPC-Web into the gRPC calls that the "backend server" is expecting. The quote does not specify where Envoy runs but generally it will be on a server you control (running it on the same server as your go backend is one option). Note that as you are using Go you may want to consider the [improbable grpcweb package](https://github.com/improbable-eng/grpc-web) because this allows you to support gRPC-Web without the need to deploy envoy.